# Android Countdown timer with double speed

Tags: android, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I would like to create a countdown timer that starts at 10 but only takes 5 seconds to count down to 0.

I have this code below from Google Source Code that counts down from 10:

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        timerText.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        timerText.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually try doing it yourself first, but:

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 500) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        timerText.setText("Half-seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 500);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        timerText.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

The `CountDownTimer` has two parameters in its constructor, one for the length of the timer as a whole (called `millisInFuture`, the first parameter), and one for how often the `onTick` function is called (which is `countDownInterval`). Both of these parameters are of the `long` variable type.

Please see [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) in the Android API.